# How can I make a button to attach files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a button that allows me to attach files, but what I have found is that I do it with input:

`<input type="file></input>"`

But I want to do it with a button using jQuery bootstrap that allows me to put any message on the button, something like:

`<button btn btn-primary> Attached to me </button>`

And in turn make the effect of it being pressed and changing depending on which button is selected, something like this:

**[Effect button pushed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuO1r.jpg)**

Comment: What code have been you trying??

Comment: `<button btn btn-primary> Attach file </button>`

I saw examples that use:

`<input type="file"></input>` 

But that throws me a simple button, i need to use bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

This could be an approaching:

```js
if (window.FileReader) {
  $('#inputImage').change(function () {
    var fileReader = new FileReader(),
        files = this.files,
        file;

    if (!files.length) {
      return;
    } else {
     $('#upload-file').addClass('active');
    }
  });
} else {
  $('#upload-file').removeClass('active');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label class="btn btn-primary" id="upload-file" title="Upload image file" for="inputImage">
    <input id="inputImage" class="hide" accept="image/*" name="file" type="file">
    Upload new image
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's what I was looking for

Comment: Look again, there are some new changes. If you think my answer is right for your question, please mark it as the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="file"></input>`. I think the syntax errors are really annoying you. Also, use something like `onclick="//function"`. I dont know css but you should make a function in javascript which will, for example, change a `<button>` value using `document.getElementById(buttonId).innerHTML`. Work your way with the design.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="test" style="display:none"/> 
<button id="testbtn" class="button">Attached to me</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#testbtn').click(function(){ $('#test').trigger('click'); });
```

Any CSS you want:

```
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Hope this helps.
https://jsfiddle.net/hog0rozg/